# telerik wpf drag drop visual feedback indicator

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, telerik

I am using Telerik in a WPF app and am using their Drag/drop manager. Everything is fine, except I want to get rid of that pesky arrow that appears before the rendering of the template view.

I am attaching a screen grab using their WPF demo on the drag/drop demo. The area that's highlighted with the red rectangle is NOT part of the template you specify in telerik - and I want to hide it.

[image]

Any help would be, of course, very greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't it just a [drag visual](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/dragdropmanager/how-to/dragdrompmanager-howto-set-drag-visual)?

Comment: No, that arrow originates outside of the supplied Template